# MAUI: Power button + Volum button click event

Tags: maui

Is it possible to trigger an event on mobile app when tapping power button and volume button together?

I need to show a secret option(a label) on the UI, when the user triggering any combination of secret key on the mobile device.

Is there any kind of options for that? I only mention power button + volume button, if any other combination available, please suggest that?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on  hardware buttons. They might work differently on each platform or device type, so there's no guarantee that they will always work. Additionally, I would expect that certain combinations are reserved for the OS, such as Power Button + Volume Down, which is used on certain iOS devices to turn the device off or reboot it. You could add a TapGestureRecognizer to some other control instead and wait for a certain amount of taps to trigger some action.

Comment: @Julian I also got the same feeling; after researching, I didn't get any useful solution. So, adding TapGestureRecognizer for the other UI controls is the best option. Lets wait for any other opinion and proceed.

Comment: This isn't really a matter of opinion but rather limitations of the device and OS manufacturers coupled with a cross-platform approach. I don't see a common denominator that is guaranteed to work except for some button or tap gesture on some control that works on all available platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are natively unavailable features, more information is in the below links (Assuming you are interested in power button):

[https://www.macrodroidforum.com/index.php?threads/how-to-disable-clicking-power-button.5741/#:~:text=It%20may%20be%20something%20that,this%20way%20I'm%20afraid](https://www.macrodroidforum.com/index.php?threads/how-to-disable-clicking-power-button.5741/#:%7E:text=It%20may%20be%20something%20that,this%20way%20I%27m%20afraid).

https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/ujoqf1/can_i_program_functionality_onto_the_side_button/

May be this was doable back in the day definitely not available anymore